# PHP CLI refuses to print errors

Tags: php, error-handling, command-line-interface

I'm running PHP 7.0.15-0ubuntu0.16.04.4 (cli) ( NTS ) and I'm trying to get the PHP CLI environment to display errors but without success. I've enabled "display_errors" in php.ini (and verified that /etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini is being parsed using "php --ini") but no errors are being displayed.

I then placed the following code at the start of my PHP CLI command:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 'stdout');
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1); 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

and inserted the following code at into my PHP code (which should trigger errors):

```
$x = $y;   // $y is undefined
$x = 1/0;  // division by zero
```

Still, no errors are being displayed, the code just executes happily over those two lines in silence and then continues to execute the rest of my code. If I do a

```
print ini_get('max_execution_time');
```

it prints "stdout", so I would expect errors to be displayed.

Does anybody know what's going on here and how I can get the PHP CLI environment to print errors?

Comment: please check that any errors shown after changing `ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1); ` to  `ini_set('display_errors', 1); `

Comment: Did as you asked (removed display_startup_errors and set 'display_errors' to 1) and still no errors are shown.

Comment: Yes, also remove `ini_set('display_errors', 'stdout');` and change `print` to `print_r(ini_get('max_execution_time'))`.

Comment: print_r(ini_get('max_execution_time')) prints "0" (without the quotes).

Comment: if it is still not working, please try to check the php.ini  with `cat php.ini | grep 'disable_functions'` that disabled `ini_set` or not

Comment: disable_functions is empty ... I can also tell that the ini_set('display_errors', [value]) works since if I check it with ini_get() the value I previously set is returned.

Comment: Problem solved. I had the Tracy debugging enabled and apparently in CLI mode it makes all errors disappear ... disabling it in CLI mode made my errors appear again.